# lightdm-greeter: disabling hibernation

Tags: debian, xfce, power-management

On my Debian/testing systems I'd like to disable just the hibernation command from the graphical login, it should be possible to suspend the system only after logging in.

I am using lightdm as a greeter and I came across a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137336/how-do-i-remove-the-shutdown-button-only-on-the-login-screen) which unfortunately didn't solve my case: d-feet reports that org.freedesktop.consolekit* does not exist (it was [removed from Debian altogether](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911416))

Using the [settings tool](https://launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings) I removed the whole power menu, since this is an acceptable workaround for me at present, but I wonder: is there a way to selectively disable specific entries in the greeter power menu?